# Adding custom test fields to magento packslip

Tags: orders, pdf

i want to add custom field to packslip infact want new format for it as below:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Customer Shipping Add</td></tr>
<tr><td>Admin Address or store address</td></tr>
<tr><td>some other detail</td></tr>
</table>
```

i found page "app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/shipment.php"

```
public function getPdf($shipments = array())
```

how to add this to my pdf